# Google AMP of iOS Chromes wastes quarter of screen

Tags: google-chrome, ios

Google AMP results show on mobile search results, leading to pages like the following on iOS Chrome:

[image]

This wastes about a quarter of my phone's screen compared to normal results, e.g.

[image]

On non-AMP pages, the address bar of Chrome for iOS normally hides as you scoll down, but not with AMP.

Is there a way to disable AMP, get the address bar and AMP banner to hide, or easily get to the original page from an AMP page?

Comment: I've found what I believe is unquestionably the right answer, care to elaborate on anything that's unsatisfactory about it or else accept it?

Comment: I think Google will realize that it needs to scroll eventually.  It is annoying.  I also don't think @owlswipe answer is "unquestionably the right answer" because requesting the desktop page gets the desktop page, not the mobile page.  I think I'll go send Chrome feedback on this issue.

Comment: Google forum: https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/ios/im-not-sure/07wMebDNwk4

Answer (score 1):

You can easily hide that AMP banner by loading the regular page instead of the AMP page. To do that, hit the three dots in the top-right and choose `Request Desktop Site`. This works in the iOS and Android versions of Chrome.

For more on what AMPs are, visit [ampproject.org](https://www.ampproject.org/).